# Zend Soap server example

Tags: php, web-services, soap, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm trying to setup soap server by following https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-01-24-zend-soap-server.html tutorial.

My corresponding changes

```
<?php
namespace Soap\Controller;

use Soap\Model;
use Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover as WsdlAutoDiscover;
use Zend\Soap\Server as SoapServer;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class SoapController extends AbstractActionController{

    private $env;

    public function __construct(Model\Env $env){
        $this->env = $env;
    }

    public function wsdlAction(){
        /** @var \Zend\Http\Request $request */
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if (!$request->isGet()) {
            return $this->prepareClientErrorResponse('GET');
        }

        $wsdl = new WsdlAutoDiscover();

        $wsdl = new WsdlAutoDiscover();
        $this->populateServer($wsdl);

        /** @var \Zend\Http\Response $response */
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/wsdl+xml');
        $response->setContent($wsdl->toXml());
        return $response;
    }

    private function prepareClientErrorResponse($allowed){
        /** @var \Zend\Http\Response $response */
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(405);
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Allow', $allowed);
        return $response;
    }

    private function populateServer($server){
        // Expose a class and its methods:
        $server->setClass(Model\Products::class);

        // Expose an object instance and its methods:
        $server->setObject($this->env);

        // Expose a function:
        $server->addFunction('Soap\Model\Env\ping');
        $server->addFunction('Soap\Model\Env\pong');
    }

    public function serverAction(){
        /** @var \Zend\Http\Request $request */
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if (!$request->isPost()) {
            return $this->prepareClientErrorResponse('POST');
        }

        // Create the server
        $server = new SoapServer(
            $this->url()
                ->fromRoute('soap/wsdl', [], ['force_canonical' => true]),
            [
                'actor' => $this->url()
                    ->fromRoute('soap/server', [], ['force_canonical' => true]),
            ]
        );
        $server->setReturnResponse(true);
        $this->populateServer($server);

        $soapResponse = $server->handle($request->getContent());

        /** @var \Zend\Http\Response $response */
        $response = $this->getResponse();

        // Set the headers and content
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml');
        $response->setContent($soapResponse);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

After running the server I'm getting error 
`Call to undefined method Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover::setObject()`

When I checked in source of AutoDiscover there is no setObject, What changes do I do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `populateServer` method from the link you posted:

```
use Acme\Model;

function populateServer($server, array $env)
{
    // Expose a class and its methods:
    $server->setClass(Model\Calculator::class);

    // Or expose an object instance and its methods.
    // However, this only works for Zend\Soap\Server, not AutoDiscover, so
    // should not be used here.
    // $server->setObject(new Model\Env($env));

    // Expose a function:
    $server->addFunction('Acme\Model\ping');
}
```

And the note just below that:

> [...] if you want to create logic that can be re-used between the Server and AutoDiscover instances, you must confine your usage to setClass(). If that class requires constructor arguments or other ways of setting instance state, you should vary the logic for creation of the WSDL via AutoDiscover and creation of the server via Server.